# Extract element from pandas list-series and store as separate series

Tags: python, pandas, list, extract, expand

I have this df (with sample desired result)

```
dfn = pd.DataFrame({"country_code": ["USA, UK, FRA", "RUS, ZHC, JAP", "IN, BRA, ES"], 
                    "all_but_american_desired": [["United Kingdom", "France"], ["Russia", "China", "Japan"], ["India", "Spain"]]})
```

where I "translate" the (so far) strings into new meanings and store as a list of elements

```
masked = {"USA":"United States", "UK":"United Kingdom", "FRA":"France", 
          "RUS":"Russia", "ZHC":"China", "JAP":"Japan", 
          "IN":"India", "BRA":"Brazil", "ES":"Spain"}

dfn["country_name"] = dfn["country_code"].apply(lambda x: [", ".join({masked[i] for i in x.split(", ")})])
```

I would then want to extract some of the translated country_name series going by an external list, `american`and place them on a separate series (`all_but_american`)

```
american = ["United States", "Brazil"]
```

Result should be same as the `all_but_american_desired` series. What I've tried so far:

```
dfn["all_but_american1"] = dfn["country_name"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in american])
```

I've used the attempt1 very same approach previously and it's worked, but this time nothin's working and I can't find the reason for it (I've also tried other approaches this time, but as I'm not familiar with them I'll refrain from posting)... Can someone check it please? If possible with an explanation as to what I'm doing wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `country_name` create lists instead one element list with joined values:

```
dfn["country_name"] = dfn["country_code"].apply(lambda x: [masked[i] for i in x.split(", ")])
```

And then your second solution working well:

```
american = ["United States", "Brazil"]

dfn["all_but_american1"] = dfn["country_name"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in american])
print (dfn)
    country_code  all_but_american_desired  \
0   USA, UK, FRA  [United Kingdom, France]   
1  RUS, ZHC, JAP    [Russia, China, Japan]   
2    IN, BRA, ES            [India, Spain]   

                              country_name         all_but_american1  
0  [United States, United Kingdom, France]  [United Kingdom, France]  
1                   [Russia, China, Japan]    [Russia, China, Japan]  
2                   [India, Brazil, Spain]            [India, Spain]
```

Comment: Hero! Valid answer as always. Thanks @jezrael! 
I'm curious tho, if you'd endulge, would it be possible to "extract" and "explode" the country_name series upon it's very creation into a separate one containing only the items on the american list? Instead of creating it "from scratch"? I'm not sure how pythonic or efficient that would be (probably not very much), but would like to see how that would look like (lambda or regular function)

Comment: @cjcrm Not 100% sure if understand, do you want  `df. explode('all_but_american_desired')`?

Comment: No, I'm saying, instead of creating "all_but_american" using that lambda, create it on the same line where we create "country_name", making it "expand" if the resulting list from the masked elements includes elements from the "american" list. If it's too hard to explain, it'd definitely not be very pythonic, but sounds like a good experiment :)

Comment: @cjcrm - I think I understand, use `dfn["all_but_american1"] = dfn["country_code"].apply(lambda x: [masked[i] for i in x.split(", ") if masked[i] not in american])`

Comment: Close - The result of that is the same as the current `all_but_american1` just bypassing the creation of the `country_name` series. What I'm saying is, instead of completely filtering out the `american` elements, "extract"/"explode" those elements to be stored on another series.
Off-topic-ish: would also like to know if there's a way to add the last element of a list-series (eg `country_name`) to another list-series (eg `all_but_american1`) if they fulfill certain criteria. So, for example, add `country_name[-1]` to `all_but_american1` if that element == "Japan"

Comment: @cjcrm - I think the best create new question - for first is possible use `dfn["all_but_american1"] = dfn["country_name"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in american])`  and `dfn["all_american1"] = dfn["country_name"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in american])` or custom function with append to 2 lists

Comment: Yeah, makes sense to split the questions. Again, thank you very much @jezrael, much appreciated!